# how to calculate the integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\displaystyle\frac{x^\beta\cos(ax)}{x^2-b^2}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

How to calculate the following definite integrals $?$:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\large\beta}\cos\left(ax\right) \over x^{2} - b^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\,\,\mbox{and}\,\,\,
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\large\beta}\sin\left(ax\right) \over x^{2} - b^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\,,\,\,\,\,\,
\mbox{assuming}\ a,b > 0\ \mbox{and} \left\vert\,{\beta}\,\right\vert < 1.
$$
I found the following integral from the table of integrals:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\large\beta}\cos\left(ax - \beta\pi/2\right) \over
x^{2} - b^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x =
-\,{\pi \over 2}\,b^{\beta - 1}
\sin\left(ab - {\pi\beta \over 2}\right)
$$
but couldn't find those two. Do they exist $?$. if yes, how can I find the answer $?$.

Thank you all !.

Comment: I *suppose* that it could lead to some hypergometric functions.

Comment: It must be a $Principal\  Value$, I guess.

Comment: Probably irrelevant if you're only interested in obtaining the asymptotics, but the linked question gives a way to rigorously derive the closed form. $\int_0^\infty x^\beta/(x^2 + 1) e^{-a b x} dx$ is an integral of a product of two Meijer G-functions. There is a general result (the Mellin convolution method) that says the integral is again a G-function and another general result (Slater's theorem) that says this G-function can be expanded into a sum of generalized hypergeometric functions if $\beta \neq 0$ and $\beta \neq 1$.

Comment: @Maxim Thank you for letting me know, I am very much interested in the result you mentioned, will definitely check it out! BTW, can you please recommend some learning materials about the asymptotic approach, I am very new in this area and want to systematically learn it. Thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend Bender, Orszag, *Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers*.

Comment: @Maxim Ok! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably noticed, there are a lot of problems with numerical integration.

As I wrote in comments, there is more than likely some hypergeometric function appearing for the first integral.

Hoping no miastake, I wrote
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\displaystyle\frac{x^\beta\cos(ax)}{x^2-b^2}dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}  \sum_{n=0}^\infty b^{2n} \cos (a x) x^{\beta -2 n-2}\,dx$$
$$I_n=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos (a x) x^{\beta -2 n-2}\,dx=-a^{2 n+1-\beta} \sin \left(\pi  n-\frac{\pi  \beta }{2}\right) \Gamma (-2
   n+\beta -1)$$ which, effectively, gives
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\displaystyle\frac{x^\beta\cos(ax)}{x^2-b^2}dx=a^{1-\beta } \sin \left(\frac{\pi  \beta }{2}\right) \Gamma (\beta -1) \,
   _1F_2\left(1;\frac{2-\beta }{2},\frac{3-\beta}{2};-\frac{a^2b^2}{4} \right)$$

**Edit**

@Maxim pointed out in comments a serious mistake in my approach. As he/she wrote, with the prinicipal value, to this result must be added the term
$$\frac{\pi}{2}   b^{\beta -1} \tan \left(\frac{\pi  \beta }{2}\right) \cos (a b)$$

Similarly

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\large\beta}\sin\left(ax\right) \over x^{2} - b^{2}}\,dx=-a^{1-\beta } \cos \left(\frac{\pi  \beta }{2}\right) \Gamma (\beta
   -1) \, _1F_2\left(1;\frac{2-\beta }{2},\frac{3-\beta}{2};-\frac{a^2 b^2}{4}
   \right)-$$ $$\frac{\pi}{2}   b^{\beta -1} \cot \left(\frac{\pi  \beta
   }{2}\right) \sin (a b)$$

Comment: The integrals diverge because of the pole at $x = b$. The principal value integrals exist:
$$\operatorname {v. \! p.} \int_0^\infty \frac {x^\beta \cos a x} {x^2 - b^2} dx = \\
a^{1 - \beta} \hspace {1.5 px} \Gamma(\beta - 1) \hspace {1.5 px}
 {_1 \hspace {-1.5 px} F_2} {\left( 1; \frac {2 - \beta} 2, \frac {3 - \beta} 2;
  -\frac {a^2 b^2} 4 \right)} \sin \frac {\pi \beta} 2 +
\frac \pi 2 b^{\beta - 1} \cos(a b) \tan \frac {\pi \beta} 2, \\
a > 0, \quad b > 0, \quad -1 < \beta < 2.$$
The first term is the termwise integral of your divergent sum (with the lower limit $n = 0$).

Comment: @Maxim. Thank you ! I was hoping to get around the problem using series but I realize that, once more, this was stupid.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Thank you so much for your detailed answer, this is awesome. I have very limited knowledge of the hypergeometric function. If I want to get the asymptotic behavior of 1F2(a,b,c,z) for large |z|. Is there any reference I can find the answer? Thank you!

Comment: @Maxim.  Thank you very much for your important note on this problem.

Comment: If I want to get the asymptotic behavior of 1F2(a,b,c,z) for large |z|, or let's say I want to get the asymptotics of 1F2 in the relation above for fixed a and $\beta$ for large b, what should I do? please suggest! Thank you! @Maxim

Comment: @Yolbarsop See [DLMF 16.11](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.11). Since $z < 0$, you'll get $A ((\sqrt z)^\alpha e^{B \sqrt z} + (-\sqrt z)^\alpha e^{-B \sqrt z}) + o(|z|^{\alpha/2})$. If you're interested in the derivation, that should probably be a separate question.

Comment: @Maxim Thank you so much for your reply. Since I have no clue about this special function I will start a separate new question about the derivation, hope you could kindly help answer it. Thank you!