# What is the asymptotic behavior of $_1F_2(1; \frac{2-\beta}{2}, \frac{3-\beta}{2}; -\frac{a^2b^2}{4})$ for large b

Tags: asymptotics, hypergeometric-function

I want to obtaine the asymptotic behavior of :
$$_1F_2(1; \frac{2-\beta}{2}, \frac{3-\beta}{2}; -\frac{a^2b^2}{4})$$
for $a>0, -1<\beta<2, b\to +\infty$
Since I have very limited knowledge of hypergeometric function, it will help a lot if anyone can show me the derivation to the final answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can find it here ... https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F2/06/02/

Comment: The [integral representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3826982) can be rewritten as
$$\operatorname {v. \! p.} \int_0^\infty \frac {x^\beta \cos a x} {x^2 - b^2} dx =
\operatorname {Re} \left( \int_{[0, i, \infty + i)}
 \frac {x^\beta e^{i a x}} {x^2 - b^2} dx +
\pi i \operatorname* {Res}_{x = b}
 \frac {x^\beta e^{i a x}} {x^2 - b^2} \right).$$
The integral on the rhs is $O(b^{-2})$ by the steepest descent method. That gives the leading term for ${_1 \hspace {-1.5 px} F_2}$ (the question of how the integral representation is derived is left open though).

Comment: @ Maxim Thank you very much for your suggestion! Would you mind show me the derivation using the steepest descent method? Thank you !

Comment: Show that $[0, i, \infty + i)$ can be deformed into $[0, i \infty)$. Take $x = i b u$ and expand the non-exponential part of the integrand into series. That gives a complete asymptotic expansion for ${_1 \hspace {-1.5 px} F_2}$.

Comment: @ Maxim Thank you so much, this is awesome!

Comment: @Maxim I tried to use the method you suggested to get the first term of its asymptotics, however, I could not get the same answer as the one provided by Paul Enta. Can you please kindly show me a bit more details on this, thanks!

Comment: If you show your derivation that gives a different result, I will check it.

Comment: @Maxim I am not sure if I did it right. here it is: evaluate the integral r.h.s on the path $[0,i\infty)$ taking $x=ibu$ 
\begin{align} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\beta} e^{iax}}{x^2-b^2}dx&=-ie^{i\beta \pi /2}b^{\beta -1} \int_0^{\infty}\frac{u^{\beta} e^{-abu}}{u^2+1}du 
&=(-1)^{n+1}ie^{i\beta \pi /2}b^{\beta -1}  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty}u^{\beta +2n}e^{-abu}du 
&=(-1)^{n+1}ie^{i\beta \pi /2}b^{\beta -1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(\beta+1+2n)}{(ab)^{\beta+1+2n}}
\end{align} 
then I take the first term of its real part $$\sin(b\pi/2)b^{-2}\Gamma(\beta+1)a^{-\beta-1}$$

Comment: The end result is correct, but your integral over $x$ should be $\int_0^{i \infty}$, not $\int_0^\infty$, the factor $(-1)^{n + 1}$ should be inside the sum, and what we get is an asymptotic series which is divergent, so the last two equality signs should be asymptotic equivalence signs. Now use the formula from the linked question that gives the relation between the integral and your ${_1 \hspace {-1.5 px} F_2}$.

Comment: @Maxim Thank you for your prompt reply. In that case, I will get the first term like $_1F_2 \sim \frac{\Gamma(\beta +1)}{\Gamma(\beta -1)} (ab)^{-2}$. But according to the answer below it should be like $_1F_2 \sim \Gamma(2-\beta)\sin\left( ab+\beta\frac{\pi}{2} \right) (ab)^{\beta-1}$, this I don't quite understand.

Comment: Again, you don't show your calculations. My guess is you're forgetting the residue at $b$ and the term with $\tan(\pi \beta/2)$.

Comment: @Maxim Yes, you are right I totally forgot other terms, I thought they are not related to $_1F_2$. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition of the hypergeometric function, using the Pochhammer symbols and simplifying the factorials
\begin{align}
_1F_2(1; \frac{2-\beta}{2}, \frac{3-\beta}{2}; -\frac{a^2b^2}{4})&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(1)_k}{\left(\frac{2-\beta}{2}  \right)_k\left(\frac{3-\beta}{2}  \right)_k}\frac{1}{k!}\left( -\frac{a^2b^2}{4}\right)^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(\frac{2-\beta}{2}  \right)_k\left(\frac{3-\beta}{2}  \right)_k}\left( -\frac{a^2b^2}{4}\right)^k
\end{align}
Now, the denominators of the general term can be written for $k\ne0$ as
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{2-\beta}{2}  \right)_k\left(\frac{3-\beta}{2}  \right)_k&=\prod_{m=0}^{k-1}\left(\frac{2-\beta}{2}  +m\right)\left(\frac{3-\beta}{2} +m \right)\\
&=2^{-2k}\prod_{m=0}^{k-1}\left(2-\beta  +2m\right)\left(3-\beta +m \right)\\
&=2^{-2k}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\left(-\beta  +2m\right)\left(1-\beta +2m \right)\\
% &=2^{-2k}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\beta  +2m-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-\beta +2m +\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
% &=2^{-2k}\prod_{m=1}^{k}\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}-\beta +2m  \right)^2-\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^2\right]
\end{align}

This is very similar to the [series expansion of the Lommel function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.9.E3)
\begin{align}
s_{{\mu},{\nu}}\left(z\right)&=z^{\mu+1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{z^{2k}}{a_{k+1}(\mu,\nu)}\\
a_{k}(\mu,\nu)&=\prod_{m=1}^{k}\left((\mu+2m-1)^{2}-\nu^{2}\right)
\end{align}
valid for $\mu\pm\nu\ne-1,-3,-5\ldots$.
Few modifications on the denominators can be done:
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{2-\beta}{2}  \right)_k\left(\frac{3-\beta}{2}  \right)_k&=2^{-2k}\prod_{m=2}^{k+1}\left(-2-\beta  +2m\right)\left(-1-\beta +2m \right)\\
&=\frac{2^{-2k}}{\beta(\beta-1)}\prod_{m=1}^{k+1}\left(-2-\beta  +2m\right)\left(-1-\beta +2m \right)\\
&=\frac{2^{-2k}}{\beta(\beta-1)}\prod_{m=1}^{k+1}\left(-\frac{3}{2}-\beta  +2m-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{3}{2}-\beta +2m +\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{align}

Thus,
\begin{equation}
_1F_2(1; \frac{2-\beta}{2}, \frac{3-\beta}{2}; -\frac{a^2b^2}{4})=\beta(\beta-1)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k\left( ab \right)^{2k}}{a_{k+1}\left( -1/2-\beta,1/2\right)}
\end{equation}
Finally,
\begin{equation}
_1F_2(1; \frac{2-\beta}{2}, \frac{3-\beta}{2}; -\frac{a^2b^2}{4})=\beta(\beta-1)(ab)^{\beta-1/2}s_{{-1/2-\beta},{1/2}}\left(ab\right)
\end{equation}
we have $-1/2-\beta\pm1/2\ne-1,-3\ldots$ as $-1/2<\beta<1$ if we suppose $\beta\ne0$. (In the case $\beta=0$ the hypergeometric function is simply $2\sinh(ab)/(\sqrt{\pi}ab)$.)

Using the expression of the Lommel function in terms of the second Lommel function[DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.9.E5)
\begin{align}
S_{{\mu},{\nu}}\left(z\right)&=s_{{\mu},{\nu}}\left(z\right)+\\
&+2^{\mu-1}\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\mu+\tfrac{1}{2}\nu+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\mu-\tfrac{1}{2}\nu+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\\
&\left(\sin\left(\tfrac{1}{2}(\mu-\nu)\pi\right)\,J_{\nu}\left(z\right)-\cos\left(\tfrac{1}{2}(\mu-\nu)\pi\right)\,Y_{\nu}\left(z\right)\right)
\end{align}
we deduce
\begin{align}
_1F_2(1; \frac{2-\beta}{2}, \frac{3-\beta}{2}; -\frac{a^2b^2}{4})=&
\beta(\beta-1)(ab)^{\beta-1/2}S_{-1/2 - \beta, 1/2}(ab)+\\
&+\Gamma(2-\beta)(ab)^{\beta-1}\sin\left( ab+\beta\frac{\pi}{2} \right)
\end{align}
where the explicit representations of the Bessel functions $J_{1/2}$ and $Y_{1/2}$ and the duplication formula for the Gamma function were used.

Now, the asymptotic expansion can be found by inserting the [asymptotic expansion](https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.9.E9)
\begin{equation}
S_{{\mu},{\nu}}\left(z\right)\sim z^{\mu-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}a_{k}(-\mu,\nu)z^{-2k}
\end{equation}
Here,
\begin{equation}
S_{-1/2 - \beta, 1/2}(ab)=(ab)^{-\beta-3/2}+o\left( (ab)^{-\beta-5/2} \right)
\end{equation}
Then, by keeping the term $k=0$ only, we obtain
\begin{equation}
_1F_2(1; \frac{2-\beta}{2}, \frac{3-\beta}{2}; -\frac{a^2b^2}{4})=\Gamma(2-\beta)\sin\left( ab+\beta\frac{\pi}{2} \right) (ab)^{\beta-1}+\beta(\beta-1) (ab)^{-2}+o\left( (ab)^{-3}\right)
\end{equation}
This expansion seems to be numerically correct. For example with $a=1, \beta=1/3,b=10$, we obtain $-0.1754495$ while the hypergeometric evaluation gives $-0.1753881$. For $b=100$, the numbers become $-0.000330866$ and $-0.000330872$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, quite a sophisticated approach! I have a question though, shouldn't the Sine term be  $\sin(ab-\beta \frac{\pi}{2})$?

Comment: You're welcome! I don't think so, with $\nu=1/2, w=(\mu-\nu)\pi/2$, we have
$$W=\sin\left(w\right)\,J_{1/2}\left(z\right)-\cos\left(w\right)\,Y_{1/2}\left(z\right)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}z^{-1/2}\cos(z-w)$$
and with $z=ab,\mu=-1/2-\beta$,
$$ W=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}(ab)^{-1/2}\cos(ab+\beta\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2})=-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}(ab)^{-1/2}\sin(ab+\beta\frac{\pi}{2})$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, this is clear enough and very much helpful.

Comment: Hi, dear @Paul Enta, sorry to bother you, but I have recently posted a new [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4884375/802023) about the integration of the hypergeometric function along a complex path, I have been struggling with it for a while. Would you mind taking a look at it? Thank you very much in advance!